# Interact.js after drag transform in css :hover doesn't work anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, interact.js

I've just discovered Interact.js and I managed to get it working, but after the drag (with inertia enabled), the transform in my :hover doesn't work anymore. The cursor: pointer still works though. Anyone who can think of a solution?

css:

```
.bubble:hover {
      transform: scale(1.1);
      cursor: pointer;
}
```

js:

```
interact('.bubble').draggable({
            inertia: {
                resistance: 15,
                minSpeed: 100,
                endSpeed: 50
            },
            onmove: function(e) {
                var target = e.target,
                    // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
                    x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + e.dx,
                    y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + e.dy;

                // translate the element
                target.style.webkitTransform =
                    target.style.transform =
                        'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

                // update the posiion attributes
                target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
                target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
            }
        }).on('tap', function(e) {
            console.log('tapped');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Check fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/82utnzbx

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a demo or a fiddle.

Comment: @nashcheez https://jsfiddle.net/82utnzbx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of multiple transformations you are applying on `bubble` i.e. due to `interact.js`, one `transform` is applied which changes the x and y coordinates of the object (`tranlate` property), and when you hover another `transform` is applied to `scale` the object.

So, the `transform` in your javascript overrides the one in the css.

What you have to do is combine both the `transform: translate()` and `transform: scale()` properties in your javascript itself.

You can do the above by using `jquery.hover()` and appending the already existing `transform` property with the static `transform: scale()` one via this code:

```
$(".bubble").hover(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("bubble")[0].style.transform += "scale(1.1)";
}, function() {
    // For transformation when bubble has moved already
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("bubble")[0].style.transform[0] != "s") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("bubble")[0].style.transform = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble")[0].style.transform.split(")")[0];
  } else {
    // For transformation when bubble has not moved
    document.getElementsByClassName("bubble")[0].style.transform = "";
  }
});
```

I have worked it out for you, refer code:

```js
interact('.bubble').draggable({
  inertia: {
    resistance: 15,
    minSpeed: 100,
    endSpeed: 50
  },
  onmove: function(e) {
    var target = e.target,
      // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
      x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + e.dx,
      y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + e.dy;

    // translate the element
    target.style.webkitTransform =
      target.style.transform =
      'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

    // update the posiion attributes
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
  }
}).on('tap', function(e) {
  console.log('tapped');
  e.preventDefault();
});

$(".bubble").hover(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("bubble")[0].style.transform += "scale(1.1)";
}, function() {
  // For transformation when bubble has moved already
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("bubble")[0].style.transform[0] != "s") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("bubble")[0].style.transform = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble")[0].style.transform.split(")")[0];
  } else {
    // For transformation when bubble has not moved
    document.getElementsByClassName("bubble")[0].style.transform = "";
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  background-color: #7dd3f4;
}

.bubble {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 10px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 10px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 10px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.bubble:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="bubble"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.6/interact.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Or you can check the updated [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/82utnzbx/1/).